# Adding an Uncofigured Good drive to an existing drivegroup/RAID setup

Tags: raid, megaraid, raid6, storcli

I have a machine with a few drives in it. Running `storcli /c0 show` produces this relevant info, et.al.:

```
TOPOLOGY :
========
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
DG Arr Row EID:Slot DID Type  State BT      Size PDC  PI SED DS3  FSpace TR 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 -   -   -        -   RAID6 Optl  N  90.952 TB dflt N  N   none N      N  
 0 0   -   -        -   RAID6 Optl  N  90.952 TB dflt N  N   none N      N  
 0 0   0   0:0      2   DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   1   0:1      3   DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   2   0:2      4   DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   3   0:3      5   DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   4   0:4      6   DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   5   0:5      7   DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   6   1:0      26  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   7   1:1      27  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   8   1:2      28  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   9   1:3      29  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   10  1:4      30  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   11  1:5      31  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 1 -   -   -        -   RAID6 Optl  N  90.952 TB dflt N  N   none N      N  
 1 0   -   -        -   RAID6 Optl  N  90.952 TB dflt N  N   none N      N  
 1 0   0   0:6      8   DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 1 0   1   0:7      9   DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 1 0   2   0:8      10  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 1 0   3   0:9      11  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 1 0   4   0:10     12  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 1 0   5   0:11     13  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 1 0   6   1:6      32  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 1 0   7   1:7      33  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 1 0   8   1:8      34  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 1 0   9   1:9      35  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 1 0   10  1:10     36  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 1 0   11  1:11     37  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 2 -   -   -        -   RAID5 Optl  N  90.952 TB dflt N  N   none N      N  
 2 0   -   -        -   RAID5 Optl  N  90.952 TB dflt N  N   none N      N  
 2 0   0   0:12     14  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 2 0   1   0:14     16  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 2 0   2   0:15     17  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 2 0   3   0:16     18  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 2 0   4   0:17     19  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 2 0   5   0:18     20  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 2 0   6   0:19     21  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 2 0   7   0:20     22  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 2 0   8   0:21     23  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 2 0   9   0:22     24  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 2 0   10  0:23     25  DRIVE Onln  Y   9.094 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

(...snip...)

PD LIST :
=======
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model            Sp Type 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0:0       2 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:1       3 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:2       4 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:3       5 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:4       6 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:5       7 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:6       8 Onln   1 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:7       9 Onln   1 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:8      10 Onln   1 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:9      11 Onln   1 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:10     12 Onln   1 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:11     13 Onln   1 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:12     14 Onln   2 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:13     38 UGood  - 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    D  -    
0:14     16 Onln   2 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:15     17 Onln   2 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:16     18 Onln   2 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:17     19 Onln   2 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:18     20 Onln   2 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:19     21 Onln   2 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:20     22 Onln   2 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:21     23 Onln   2 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:22     24 Onln   2 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
0:23     25 Onln   2 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
1:0      26 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
1:1      27 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
1:2      28 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
1:3      29 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
1:4      30 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
1:5      31 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
1:6      32 Onln   1 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
1:7      33 Onln   1 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
1:8      34 Onln   1 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
1:9      35 Onln   1 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
1:10     36 Onln   1 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
1:11     37 Onln   1 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, `c0/e0/d13` is flagged as UGgood (after replacing the drive), and drive group 2 is missing row 11.

What is the correct procedure, using `storcli`, to add this drive to the RAID? I would rather do it via `storcli` instead of rebooting to use the (to me) more familiar BIOS RAID tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my old knowledge of working with storcli serves me well, this should do the trick. However you’re running these commands at your risk... after all it’s your array... I’d recommend taking any answer on here and studying it against man pages etc and make sure you’re 100%

storcli /c0/e0/s13 insert dg=2 array=0 row=11

Then do storcli /c0/e0/s13 start rebuild

Comment: After checking, reading, and verifying against a machine of identical disk setup I was more than happy to try the command, but for some reason storecli gives me `There is no drive missing in DG 2 Array 0 Row 11 `. From what I can see, the numbers are correct, and googling "There is no drive" gives me no results. Any tips?

Comment: Try changing row=11 to row=0

Comment: Same result. 'no drive missing'

Comment: I am beginning to think that perhaps the array was not set up to include all disks to begin with. I just stumbled across a guide for adding a missing disks, and there the array topology lists a disk as actually missing. Could it be that the RAID needs to be extended first?

Comment: In my particular case, there were other things at play. Once I had them sorted out, the above worked just fine

Comment: Excellent! Although please feel free to de-mark this as an answer since it didn’t fully address the problem and you’ll lose 50 points! Otherwise I’m glad you’re sorted!

Comment: I'll leave it. It addressed the part of the problem that was obvious at first, to which I was having a hard time finding a canonical answer.